# body {overflow-y:hidden } but I can still scroll vertically

Tags: html, css, overflow

So, I can't get my index.php and index.css to work together to disable vertical scroll. 
I have literally been on this for about 2.5 hours and it's ridiculous because I've done it on other websites before.

However, whenever I run my index.php (locally) it won't disable the vertical scroll. It simply hides the scroll bar. I even tried to change index.php to index.html to see if that was the issue, its not, the file has no php code yet its only preparation because I am going to mak it dynamic later. Another odd thing is that it works perfectly fine in JS fiddle. Which I guess only makes it harder for you guys to help. Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/V346B/

Edit: The matter in question is, why is it working on js fiddle and not in my browser (Chrome). Also, the way I am testing it is through adding height to Wrapper, as seen below.

Edit2: Adding height:100% to body does not solve this.

The HTML:

```
<title>Bryan the Lion</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id ="wrapper">
        <div id = "header">
                <h1>Pax Frame</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">h_option</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">h_option</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">h_option</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">h_option</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        <div id ="wrapper_main">
            <div id = "main">
                <p>WTF</p>
                <div id = "nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id = "sidebar">

                </div>
                <div id ="footer">

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>




    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The CSS:

```
body { 
overflow-y:hidden; 
} 
@font-face {
font-family: "AlexBrush";
src: url(fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
}
#wrapper_main{
background: red ;
}
#wrapper{
width: 80% ;
margin: 0 auto ;
background: yellow ;
height: 1000px ;
}
#main{
background: blue ;
background-position: right ;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#header{
width: 90% ;
height: 150px ;
background: green ;
}
#header h1{
font-family: AlexBrush ;
font-size: 5em ;
}
#nav{
height: 50px ;
width: 80% ;
margin: 0 auto ;
display: block ;
background: gray ;
}   
#nav ul li{
display: inline-block;
letter-spacing: 2px ;
background: purple ;
}
#sidebar{

}
```

Please help me before I go to bed depressed because I can't figure this out.

Comment: I linked the fiddle. o.O

Comment: Try giving overflow-y:hidden; to html tag as well

Comment: I just tried it, no good. Idk what is up with this.

Comment: can you provide the dummy link of it. Atleast I can try inspect element and help you with it

Comment: I'm sorry what is a dummy link? I haven't uploaded it to the internet yet. Let me upload it and link you if that is what you mean.

Comment: http://paxframe.com/
There is the link, still not working online either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54012/discussion-between-sss-and-bryan-fajardo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving Height:100% to the wrapper. Your Body is of lesser height and in % and wrapper in pixel.

Comment: thanks man! this fixed it ! Now I can get my life back in track.
you are awesome thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

```
#header ul{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 width:140px;
 position:relative;
 height:40px;
}
#header ul li{
 list-style:none;
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid red;
 background-color:red;
 }
#header ul li a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
}
 //whter you  script
 $(#header ul).mouseover(function(){
   $(this).removeAttr("style");
 })
 $(#header ul).mouseover(function(){
   $(this).css("oveflow","auto");
 });

  // write you html

    <ul style"overflow:hidden">
        <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: thanks, I haven't had much practice with scripting but this will definitely help me